# Double Names being included in Table of Contents

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, titlesec

I have a final report that I am writing in LaTeX. I have a code to make the section headings appear in the center of the page (thanks to [Jubobs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/21891/jubobs)):

```
\titleformat{\section}
{\vspace*{\fill}\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\thesection}
{1em}
{\Large}
[\vspace*{\fill}\newpage]
```

This unfortunately creates two entries in the tableofcontents page. Deleting this code solves the ToC problem, but I still want the section headings to be centered on the page. How can this be resolved?

MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate,a4wide,graphicx,pdfpages,titlesec}
\title{Final Report}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\begin{document}

\titleformat{\section}
{\vspace*{\fill}\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\thesection}
{1em}
{\Large}
[\vspace*{\fill}\newpage]

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{name}\\[0.2cm]
    {\Large XYZ}\\[0.2cm]
    {\Large ABC}\\[2.5cm]
    {\huge \textbf{Final Report}}\\[5cm]
\end{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \emph{ABC :} \\
        \textbf{ABC} \\ ~\\
        \emph{XYZ : }\textbf{ABC}
    \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright}
        \emph{XYZ :}\\
        \textbf{ABC} \\
        \emph{XYZ :} \\
        \textbf{ABC} \\
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
\vfill
\begin{center}
    \today
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\newpage


\section{Test Section}
Test.
\newpage

\section{Test Section 2}
This is a filler.
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since `\tableofcontents` uses `\section*`, perhaps you will need to provide a different definition for starred (unnumbered) section; something like `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\vspace*{\fill}\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}{1em}
  {\Large}[\vspace*{\fill}\newpage]
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{test}

\end{document}`

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Using your code snippet does not show any problem for me.

Comment: Your MWE does not demonstrate any problems. There is no `\tableofcontents`, and no `\section`. Please make an MWE that actually has double entries in the ToC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the class for `\section` to `page` to ensure that titles will be on a page of their own; I would also suggest you to define a command to apply the modifications once special unnumbered sections, such as the ToC, LoF, LoT, have been typeset; something along the following lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\newcommand\sectformat{%
\titleclass{\section}{page}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\vfill\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {}{0em}
  {}[\vfill]%
}
\newcommand\sectionbreak{\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\sectformat
\section{Test Section One}
Test.

\section{Test Section Two}
Test.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The culprit seems to be the `\newpage` in this passage:

```
\titleformat{\section}
{\vspace*{\fill}\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\thesection}
{1em}
{\Large}
[\vspace*{\fill}\newpage]
```

The problem disappears when you remove it. Consider this example (I've removed a number of non-MWE things as well -- there were a lot, actually):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\title{Final Report}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\titleformat{\section}
{\vspace*{\fill}\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\thesection}
{1em}
{\Large}
[\vspace*{\fill}]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{Test Section}
\newpage
Test.

\newpage
\section{Test Section 2}
\newpage
This is a filler.
\end{document}
```

Now you probably still want to have the section headings appear on a separate page (like with `\part`). There's a couple of ways to do this. You may e.g. have a look a the `etoolbox` page, which allows you to prepend and append a `\newpage` to every `\section`.

Comment: How can I use the etoolbox package, through AtBeginEnvironment?

Comment: @AnavaJain, actually, I just realized `etoolbox` isn't necessary. Gonzalo's suggestion, which I endorse, is even more elegant and doesn't require an additional package, since you're using `titlesec` anyway. But [tag:etoolbox] is a great package nevertheless; something to keep in mind for whenever you need to modify existing commands (and lots of other problems as well).

Answer (score 0):

I moved the `titlesec` definition before `\begin{document}`, and provide a definition for the starred section version, that will be applied to the ToC itself, as Gonzalo suggested. As you don't want section numbers, I removed them directly at the `\titleformat` definition, and set `secnumdepth` to 1, so the normal sections and the ToC section can be distinguished.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate,a4wide,graphicx,pdfpages,titlesec}
\title{Final Report}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\titleformat{\section}
{\vspace*{\fill}\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{} % no section number
{1em}
{\Large}
[\vspace*{\fill}\newpage]

%% For the ToC
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
 {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
 {}
 {0em}
 {}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Test Section}
Test.
\newpage

\section{Test Section 2}
This is a filler.
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solves the ToC problem but the section headings need to be centered on a page and the content to start from the next page which is not happening.

Comment: @AnavaJain Please see the updated version.